# $\text{order }a\otimes b=\gcd\left(\text{order }a,\text{order }b\right)$?

Tags: abelian-groups, tensor-products

Let $A,B$ be abelian groups with $a\in A$ having order $m$ and
$b\in B$ having order $n$.

Then $m\left(a\otimes b\right)=\left(ma\right)\otimes b=0\otimes b=0$
and likewise $n\left(a\otimes b\right)=a\otimes\left(nb\right)=a\otimes0=0$.

This shows that $a\otimes b$ has finite order $k$ that divides $m$
and $n$, or equivalently $k$ *divides* $\gcd\left(m,n\right)$.

My question is:

> Can it also be shown that $k$ *equalizes* $\gcd\left(m,n\right)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can generalize this result by proving that
$\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\bigotimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$ where $d$ is gcd($m,n$)

Observe first that 
$a\bigotimes b=a\bigotimes (b.1)=(ab)\bigotimes 1=ab(1\bigotimes 1)$. Consequently, $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\bigotimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a cyclic group with $1\bigotimes 1$ as generator.

Since $m(1\bigotimes 1)=m\bigotimes 1=0\bigotimes 1=0$  and $n(1\bigotimes 1)=1\bigotimes n=1\bigotimes 1=0$, then this cyclic group has order dividing $d$.

Consider the map $\varphi :\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/d$ defined by $\varphi (a,b)=ab$ .this map is well-defined(easy to check). Evidenly $\varphi$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-linear.

By the universal property of tensor, it induces a $R$-module homorphism $\Phi :\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\bigotimes \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$ where $\phi(a\bigotimes b)=ab$.

Consider a $R$-module homorphism map defined as follows

$\Psi :\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\bigotimes \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

$\Psi(a)=a(1\bigotimes 1)$

Clearly, $\Phi \Psi =Id_{\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}}$, and $\Psi \Phi =Id_{\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\bigotimes \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}}$

Hence, $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\bigotimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$ where $d$ is gcd($m,n$) from which implies what you claim.

Answer (score 1):

The key result is: If $\sum_i{a_i}\otimes{b_i}=0$ in $A\otimes{B}$, there exist finitely generated abelian groups $A_0\subseteq{A}$ and $B_0\subseteq{B}$ such that: $a_i\in{A_0}$, $b_i\in{B_0}$ and $\sum_i{a_i}\otimes{b_i}=0$ in $A_0\otimes{B_0}$. Hence you may apply the structure theorems of finitely generated abelian groups to prove that $k=\mathrm{gcd}\{m,n\}$.

Comment: How do you prove it for finitely generated abelian groups?

Comment: Let $A_0=A_{p_1}\oplus\cdots\oplus{A_{p_t}}$ and $B_0=B_{p_1}\oplus\cdots\oplus{B_{p_t}}$ be primary decompositions, 
and $a=\sum_{i=1}^ta_i\in\oplus_i{A_{p_i}}$, $b=\sum_ib_i\in\oplus_i{B_{p_i}}$, with $ord(a_i)=p_i^{e_i}$ and $ord(b_i)=p_i^{f_i}$. 
We have $ord(a)=\prod_ip_i^{e_i}$, and $ord(b)=\prod_ip_i^{f_i}$.
Since $a\otimes{b}=\sum_ia_i\otimes{b_i}$, and $ord(a_i\otimes{b_i})=p_i^{min\{e_i,f_i\}}$ then $ord(a\otimes{b})=\prod_ip_i^{min\{e_i,f_i\}}=gcd\{ord(a),ord(b)\}$.

Comment: You reduce to the case of $p$-groups, OK. But how is the argument for $p$-groups? That is, with your notation, how do you prove $\mathrm{ord}(a_i \otimes b_i) = p_i^{\mathrm{min}(e_i,f_i)}$?

Comment: Also, what about the case that $A,B$ have torsion-free parts?

Comment: Doesn't it already fail when $A,B$ are cyclic $p$-groups?

Comment: In fact, if $m\leq{n}$, we have: $\mathbb{Z}_{p^m}\otimes\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}\cong\mathbb{Z}_{p^m}$. It is not necessary to consider the torsion-free part as $a$ and $b$ have finite order.